# How to tie a formula to a specific row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Let's say I Have that formula in the picture at `B2`. I always thought it is natural to add more rows to the top of the page to add more data so I can see them first as more recent. My problem is now that when I insert a new row at line 4 for example the formula changes to `= MOD (count (B`**5**`:B), 12)`, so It misses the information I have just entered. How to tie this formula to the 4th row no matter what happens to the table?

I came up with Idea of just adding an empty row and adding information after that or use `INDIRECT` somehow, but from what I understood it will hard to change the formula itself then dragging it to other columns. Say dragging it from `B` to `C` won't change it automatically to `MOD (count (C4:C))` which is desirable here.

Well I think I am just looking for the best method.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change your formula to include the blank row3.

Like this:
`=MOD(COUNTA(B3:B),12)`

**Inserting a new row**

- To insert a new row at the top of the range, click on the first row that contains data - in this case, it is Row#4 ("12-Mar"). A new row#4 will be created.
- Enter the date/data into that cell, and the adjacent cell in Column B.
- Because the range in your formula begins with Row 3, any data in the new row will be automatically included in the formula.